# How to get information inside HTML >< tags

Tags: c#

I have seen other people ask this question but I just can't wrap my head around it...

```
<div class=\"col - md - 4 queryResponseBodyKey\">.*</div>
```

I am trying to get information from this. I basically go to a website, download the HTML information and then display it nicely inside of my program. But I just can't seem to figure out how a regex works.

Currently my code is:

```
 string nopInput = URL;
        var nopPattern = Regex.Match(nopInput, "<div class=\"col - md - 4 queryResponseBodyKey\">.*</div>");
        MessageBox.Show(nopPattern.ToString());
        lb_name.Text = "Name: " + nopPattern.ToString();
```

But it doesn't return anything... Can someone help me?

Comment: Regex isn't the best thing to be using to parse html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: nopPattern is a `Match`, not a `String`. Use the `Match.Value` property.